# Cannot retrieve spinner values from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-spinner

I have used a database class, datamodel class and main activity in my application. I am not populating spinner values from sqlite database but I am storing selected spinner values in db. I have a text entry too. I declared datamodel object separately.
 `StudentModel student=new StudentModel();`
I have used this is at two diff places.The first one inside Onclick(text)

```
if(v == findViewById(R.id.add)){
        tv.setText("");
        student.name = name.getText().toString();
        }
```

The next inside OnItemSelected(Spinner)

```
student.subject=subject.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

In the databasehelper class I insert value like

```
public long addStudentDetail(StudentModel student) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_SUBJECT, student.subject);
    values.put(KEY_NAME, student.name);
    long insert = db.insert(TABLE_STUDENT, null, values);
    return insert;
}
```

And in the databasehelper class I retrieve them like

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            StudentModel students = new StudentModel();
            students.id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ID));
            students.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_NAME));
            students.subject = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SUBJECT));
            studentsArrayList.add(students);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'subject' does not exist` while running.

Comment: dump your `Cursor` to see what's inside it: `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`

Comment: It shows the previously entered values in the db(when I got subject using text from the user).I setup spinner and I get this problem.Then should the problem should be because of insertion?I have edited my post to show insertion code as well.

Comment: so what are the columns in the cursor?

Comment: 0 {
04-02 16:19:04.473 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out:    id=3
04-02 16:19:04.473 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out:    subject=Science
04-02 16:19:04.473 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out:    name=shrei
04-02 16:19:04.473 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out: }
04-02 16:19:04.474 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out: 1 {
04-02 16:19:04.474 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out:    id=5
04-02 16:19:04.474 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out:    subject=social
04-02 16:19:04.474 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out:    name=abc
04-02 16:19:04.474 2935-2935/myworkI/System.out: }

Comment: ok,  why dont you use a SimpleCursorAdapter for your spinner?

Comment: okay!I'll try that.Thanks for guiding me.But what do you think is the problem with what I have done?

Comment: i have no idea,  reading seems to be ok, use SimpleCursorAdapter,  it is much more easier